# How do I disable system created notifications when my app is in the foreground?

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I need help with a small thing in react native . . .

Is even possible to enable/disable system notifications alerts if the app is open ? In my case I have an internal notifications system implemented in the app so the user does not want system notifications to popup if the app is open. (I'm using react-native-firebase for notifications)

Answer (score 1):

You can use React Natives own [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate) api to determine whether the application is in the foreground (appState = `active`) and programatically use that to determine whether or not to show the notification.

FCM messages sent with `notification` properties are automatically handled by the OS - you could switch to data-only FCM messages and then programmatically create and display (if app not active) your notifications based off your data properties.

- See [React Native Firebase - Messaging Introduction](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/messaging/introduction#Message-types) for descriptions of these types of messages.
- See [React Native Firebase - Android - FCM messages in the background](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/messaging/receiving-messages#4)-(Optional)(Android-only)-Listen-for-FCM-messages-in-the-background) for how to setup a background service/HeadlessJS task to handle data-only messages and using them to create your own notifications.

Comment: data only notifications don't get evaluated when app is terminated

Answer (score 0):

For
Android

```
<meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground" android:value="false"/>
```

iOS

```
// Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);
}
```

It will not show popup when app is in foreground.